# Running javascript every time page is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, userscripts

I have a userscript that I need to run EVERY time ANY page to which the userscript is attached is modified by AJAX. Is there any method to listen the XMLHttpRequest-s?

Comment: Are you using jQuery for your Ajax requests? You could use the http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ method.

Comment: @Andy I want to listen all Ajax request, not only mine. It's an userscript which should run on all pages in the web.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell exactly what you are looking for without the code you are using, but I hope this is useful.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://yoururl");
request.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // HERE RUN THE FUNCTION YOU WANT TO RUN AGAIN
    }
};
request.send();
```

Comment: I dont want to create a new request. In example i want ot run script every time i change page in Google.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get it you want a certain script to run everytime the page is modified by an ajax request.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("an ajax request was completed);
});
```

if you replace the console.log with your code, it will run everytime when an ajax request is completed on the document (webpage).

to check it without using jquery this should work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18259603/4194167

also don't forget to add

```
@run-at document-start
```

to your userscript, it needs to be loaded before the webpage is running.

Comment: I think this would only happen if the userscript is using the version of jquery on the host page rather that its own.

Comment: What happen when host page not using jquer??

Comment: if the page is not using jquery nothing happens, i don't know if the version has to be the same, answer editted